# Link alternate hreflang two links with same language, SEO?

Tags: html, hyperlink, alternate, hreflang

I am displaying these alternate links in the header:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://mysite/en/home/"/>
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" href="http://mysite/fr/home/"/>
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://mysite/home/"/>
```

The default lang is English, but for those who have a browser in French it will display the site in French according to `$browserLang = substr(@$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);`

Is it a problem for the SEO having 2 links with the same hreflang?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an SEO question outside [the scope defined by the SEO tag wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/seo/info). It might be on-topic for [the webmasters stackexchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score -2):

perhaps use hreflang="x-defaults" for default la

Comment: Describe it as answer or write it as a comment .